# Are there functions that have $\Re(f(z))$ periodic but $f(z)$ is not periodic?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

Let $f(z)$ be a function meromorphic in a simply connected convex domain $D$ (subset of the complex plane with positive area or the whole complex plane) where $z$ is a complex number.

Are there such functions $f(z)$ where $\Re(f(z))$ is periodic in the domain (no periods larger than the domain please :p ) but $f(z)$ is not periodic? (if $D\subset \mathbb C$ it is clear that $f(z)$ is not periodic but $\Re(f(z))$ might still be for some shapes of $D$).

In particular the case when $D = \mathbb C$ is interesting. (in other words $f(z)$ meromorphic over $\mathbb C$)

I guess it is a similar question to ask about $\Im$ , $\operatorname{Arg}$ or $|\cdot|$ instead of $\Re$.

I read about double periodic functions and Cauchy-Riemann equations but I still don't know. I can't find such a function in the literature ( i mean the one i search here , i don't mean i can't find a double periodic one in the literature of course ) and I don't know how to construct them or even if they exist.

Comment: The literature is literally filled with examples of doubly periodic functions. They are called *elliptic functions*. You can find them constructed in pretty much every textbook on complex analysis —Lang's, Ahlfors's, &c.

Comment: I was referring to the functions i was looking for. Maybe an edit.

Comment: Also, your parenthetical remark in the 2nd paragraph that something is clear is quite weird: there certainly are  periodic functions defined on proper subsets of the complex plane; for example, restrict any periodic function from the plane to any open subset of the plane invariant under the periods.

Comment: A function cannot repeat its period 2 times and then diverge when it is suppose to reach its 3rd repeat. At least not a function that is holomorphic in its period.

Comment: I do not know what your last comment means.

Comment: I thought reading about double periodic functions and Cauchy-Riemann equations would help , but its much simpler as you have shown. Oh well , it was fun reading anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is meromorphic in $\mathbb C$ and its real part is periodic of period $p$. Then $z\mapsto f(z)-f(z+p)$ is a meromorphic function whose real part is identically zero.

Can you conclude something from this?

Comment: Of course ! So simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The real part of $z\mapsto iz$ has period $p$ for any $p\in \mathbb R$.